# Our Facebook application allows you to "invite your friends". How can you track how many friends each person invites?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, analytics

One of the actions we encourage within our Facebook app is inviting your friends to try it. Is there a way to see how many friends each individual user invites? For instance, if we ran a contest that gives away free swag for anyone that invites 10 or more friends, how could we track which users that fit that criteria?

Answer (score 0):

Such a contest would be explicitly against Facebook's policies, and forcing or incentivizing users to send out requests en-masse results in higher spam reports which may result in your app losing the ability to send requests, but:

- You can use the callback of the [Requests Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) which contains the request ID and the list of recipients to track who the requests were sent to

And/Or

- You can use the `data` attribute of the request to store tracking information, and extract that when processing the accepted request